# Is the formula $\;\oint H(x) \, \delta(y) \, dy = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint d\phi\;$ well known?

Tags: integration, reference-request, dirac-delta, computational-geometry, winding-number

Explanation - everything real-valued:
$$
(x,y) = \mbox{cartesian coordinates} \\
\phi = \mbox{angle, in polar coordinates} \\
H(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{for} & x < 0 \\ 1 & \mbox{for} & x > 0 \end{cases} \quad \mbox{: Heaviside function}\\
\delta(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{for} & y \ne 0 \\ \infty & \mbox{for} & y = 0 \end{cases} \quad \mbox{and} \quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(y) \,dy = 1 \quad \mbox{: Dirac delta}
$$
The meaning of the formula is a topological one:

#### Crossing number = Winding number

Here is a visualization. WLOG the origin $(0,0)$ is taken at the black dots inside/outside a domain. The integrations are carried out over the boundary of that domain.

[image]

A **proof** of the formula is found
[**at this place**](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/grondig/topology.htm).
I want to know if this formula has been found by others (< 2005); any references would be quite welcome.

Comment: if we attend just to the notation we will have that $$\oint H(x)\delta(y) d(y)=H(x)\oint \delta(y)d(y)=i H(x)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{is}\delta(e^{i s})ds=0$$

Comment: @Masacroso: The infinitesimal $dy$ is not meant to be an arc-length increment. I've updated the question accordingly. Sorry if I've caused any confusion.

Comment: I think I have seen this in computational geometry for solid (CAD) operations: take a point, shoot a ray out to infinity, count the number of intersections, odd number of intersections means the point is on the inside of the domain. I think you may find it in books and papers on "constructive solid geometry", perhaps under "ray shooting".

Comment: @Jap88: Hmm, I've always thought that CSG (Computational Solid Geometry) is 3-D. But my statement is 2-D (though it is "ray shooting" indeed). How does the 3-D compare with the 2-D?

Comment: From a ray shooting perspective 2D and 3D is more or less the same thing. Formulating it as integrals will be a bit different I think in 3D and probably quite a bit more difficult and technical.