# Transforming a numerically unstable line integral into a (more) stable one

Tags: numerical-methods, polar-coordinates, line-integrals

Given a closed planar curve $\Gamma(t) = \big(x(t), y(t)\big)$, say $t \in [0,1]$, and a point $P = (x_P, y_P)$ in its interior,  I'm interested in computing the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^1 f(t) \frac{R(t) \cdot N(t)}{\|R(t)\|^2} dt,$$

where $f(t)$ is a known function, $R(t) = \Gamma(t) - P$ and $N(t)$ is the *unnormalised* normal vector at $\Gamma(t)$ pointing away from the interior. Now, for a point $P$ close to the boundary (which results in a small $\|R\|$), the denominator becomes an issue when trying to compute/approximate the integral using a numerical approach. **I'm therefore looking for a way to transform this integral into something that is easier to work with from a numerical point of view.**

So far, I found that the integral is similar to the one that can be used to compute the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Differential_geometry) for $P$ in $\Gamma(t)$. Recall that the winding number $w$ is essentially the number of (counter-clockwise) rotations an observer standing at $P$ makes while tracking an object traversing the curve from start to end. Note that without loss of generality, we can assume $P$ to be at the origin (i.e. we can move the curve — with $P$ in it — such that $P$ ends up at the origin). Then, if we express $\Gamma(t)$ as $\big(r(t), \theta(t)\big)$, with $r^2(t) = x^2(t) + y^2(t)$ and $\theta(t) = \mathrm{atan}\big(y(t), x(t)\big)$, we get

$$2\pi w = \theta(1) - \theta(0) = \oint_\Gamma d\theta = \int_0^1 \frac{d\theta}{dt} dt = \int_0^1 \frac{x(t)\frac{dy}{dt} - y(t)\frac{dx}{dt}}{x^2(t) + y^2(t)} dt.$$

Note that the tangent vector of $\Gamma(t)$ is $\frac{d\Gamma}{dt} = \left( \frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt} \right)$, and assuming $\Gamma(t)$ to be parameterised counter-clockwise, the normal follows as $N(t) = \left( \frac{dy}{dt}, -\frac{dx}{dt} \right)$. Therefore, we obtain

$$w = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{R(t) \cdot N(t)}{\|R(t)\|^2} dt,$$

which is similar to the integral I'm interested in. Why this detour? Well, **I wondered whether this approach could perhaps be applied in reverse and obtain an integral $\oint_\Gamma \ldots d\theta$**, which would be great as such an integral is (much) easier to work with from a numerical perspective (i.e. no nasty denominator).

Finally, the following alternative way of expressing $w$ might be helpful:

$$w= \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_\Gamma \frac{R(t) \cdot N(t)}{\|R(t)\|^2 \|\frac{d\Gamma}{dt}\|} d\Gamma = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_\Gamma \frac{1}{\|R(t)\|} \left( \frac{R(t)}{\|R(t)\|} \cdot \frac{N(t)}{\|N(t)\|} \right) d\Gamma = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_\Gamma \frac{1}{\|R(t)\|} \cos \varphi(t) d\Gamma,$$

where $\varphi(t)$ is the angle between $R(t)$ and $N(t)$.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: __[Is the formula $\;\oint H(x)\,\delta(y)\,dy = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint d\phi\;$ well known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385501/is-the-formula-oint-hx-deltay-dy-frac12-pi-oint-d-phi)__

Comment: "$N(t)$ is the unnormalised normal vector..." What is the unnormalized normal vector? The integral clearly does depend on its choice...

Comment: Do we know anything about the ratio $||N(t)||/||R(t)||$ ?  (Just trying an idea.)

Comment: @fedja $N(t)$ is the tangent vector $T(t) = \frac{d\Gamma}{dt}$ rotated by $90^\circ$ degrees (counter-clockwise for a clockwise parameterisation and vice versa). If we assume the parameterisation to be arbitrary, we cannot say anything about the length of $N(t)$.

Comment: @PatrickHew I don't think so. Only if we assume the parameterisation to be regular, we get $\|N(t)\| > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a "brutal" approximation.

Rewrite the integral as
$$
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^1 f(t) \frac{R(t) \cdot N(t) \, ||N(t)||}{||R(t)||^2||N(t)||} \, dt
=
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^1 f(t) \frac{||N(t)||}{||R(t)||} \cos\bigl(\theta(t)\bigr) \, dt
$$
where $\theta(t)$ is the acute angle between $N(t)$ and $R(t)$. Then chop the domain of the integrand into four portions:

1. A portion where $||R(t)||$ is large.
2. A portion where $||R(t)||$ is small and $\cos\bigl(\theta(t)\bigr)$ is small.
3. Another portion where $||R(t)||$ is small and $\cos\bigl(\theta(t)\bigr)$ is small.
4. A portion where $||R(t)||$ is small and $\cos\bigl(\theta(t)\bigr)$ is large.

Then integrate over portions (1) and (4), and ignore (2) & (3).

(Think of $\Gamma$ as the unit circle.  Imagine $p = (1-\delta,0)$ for small $\delta > 0$.  Then "zoomed up close" to $p$, $\Gamma$ looks like the line $x=1$.)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not quite work — when $R(t)$ is small, it generally points in approximately the same direction as $N(t)$, so $\cos\big( \theta(t) \big) \approx 1$. These contributions should not be ignored.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the above a bit. In comparison to portion (4), the contributions from portions (2) and (3) might indeed be negligible — (considerably) larger $\|R\|$ and smaller $\cos\big( \theta(t) \big)$ — but this does not solve the main issue, which is the integration of portion (4).

Answer (score 1):

(This one is a bit of a handwaving guess - details may need checking.)

Rewrite the integral as
$$\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^1 f(t) \frac{R(t) \cdot N(t) \, ||N(t)||}{||R(t)||^2||N(t)||} \, dt
&=
  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^1 f(t) \frac{||N(t)||}{||R(t)||} \cos\bigl(\theta(t)\bigr) \, dt
\\ &=
  \text{Re} \left[ \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_\Gamma g(z) \, dz \right]
\end{align*}$$
where $g(z) = \displaystyle f(z) \frac{||N(z)||}{||R(z)||} e^{iz}$.

Find the points $\{a_k\}_k$ on the interior of $\Gamma$ where $g$ is not holomorphic.  This would be $p$ and perhaps others.

Apply the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)
$$
  \oint_\Gamma g(z) \, dz
  =
  2\pi i \sum_k \text{Res}(g, a_k)
$$

Comment: I like the idea, but there are no singularities in the interior — the integral only becomes problematic upon approaching the boundary.

Comment: I *think* $g(z)$ has at a singularity at $z = p$ as $||R(p)|| = 0$ (?)

Comment: Is $p$ the same as the $P$ I defined above, i.e. as a point in the interior? Then we have $\|R(P)\| > 0$.

Comment: Yes, I should have written $P$.  In my understanding, $R(z)$ is the vector from $P$ to $z$.  So certainly for any $z \in \Gamma$, $||R(z)||>0$.  But to apply the Residue theorem we also want to understand behaviour on the interior of $\Gamma$.  And hence $P$ is a singularity.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. You're right, if we modify $R$ such that it can take on points that are *not* on $\Gamma$, then $\|R(P)\| = 0$. However, for interior points, $N$ is not defined... Furthermore, when going from $\int_0^1 \ldots dt$ to $\oint_\Gamma \ldots dz$, should we not introduce a factor $\frac{1}{\|N\|}$ as I did towards the end of my question?

Comment: I multiplied by $||N||/||N||$. I *think* the $1/||N||$ factor gets absorbed by the $\cos \varphi(t)$, to leave a $||N||$ factor in the numerator.

Comment: Correct, but I meant that switching from $dt$ to $d\Gamma$ introduces $1 / \| \frac{d\Gamma}{dt} \| = 1 / \|N(t)\|$. I suppose the same happens when switching from $dt$ to $dz$.